# How local SVN server work?

Tags: svn

I follow this tutorial to create a svn

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/10/29/creating-local-svn-repository-home-repository/

However after running

`$ svn import /home/user/project1 file:///home/user/svnrep/project1/trunk -m "Initial import of project1"`

I can't find any file in `/home/user/svnrep/project1/trunk`

I still can check out to any folder using `svn co /home/user/svnrep/project1/trunk` but It doesn't look the same as a repo server when I can browse the actual files inside `trunk`

Like this example: `http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/`

Can someone explain to my how it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't find anything resembling your project's structure under the repository's URL, even if it is a file URL and not a HTTP URL. You shouldn't care for what you could find there. SVN implements the repository with a database, you will not find the file structure of your project matched with a file structure in the repository path.

You should find some folders below `svnrep` like `conf`, `db` and `hooks`. But don't mess there unless you know what you do.

If you want to browse the repository like you could with the Google Code repository you have to setup an HTTP server that can present the SVN. An Apache is typically used for this. See for example [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) to see how it is configured with Ubuntu. Or you just browse the repository with a SVN tool like Tortoise or Subclipse.